# How to prevent comma in VimL string concatenation?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I have an object defined like so:

```
let g:lightline = {
      \ 'component': {
      \   'fugitive': '%{exists("*fugitive#statusline") ? "⎇ " . fugitive#statusline() : ""}'
      \ },
  \ }
```

The output of `fugitive#statusline()` is `GIT(master)`, so the final string eventually appears in my statusline as `⎇ ,GIT(master)` with a comma.

Why is there a comma? How can we avoid the comma?

I'm using lightline.vim to customize my status line, and the whole configuration looks like this:

```
let g:lightline = {
      \ 'active': {
      \   'left': [
      \       [ 'mode', 'paste' ],
      \       [ 'filename', 'readonly', 'modified' ],
      \       [ 'fugitive', ],
      \   ]
      \ },
      \ 'inactive': {
      \   'left': [
      \       [ 'filename', 'readonly', 'modified' ],
      \       [ 'fugitive', ],
      \   ]
      \ },
      \ 'component': {
      \   'readonly': '%{&readonly?"x":""}',
      \   'fugitive': '%{exists("*fugitive#statusline") ? "⎇ " . fugitive#statusline() . "" : ""}'
      \ },
      \ 'component_visible_condition': {
      \   'fugitive': '(exists("*fugitive#head") && ""!=fugitive#head())'
      \ },
      \ 'separator': { 'left': '', 'right': '' },
      \ 'subseparator': { 'left': '|', 'right': '|' }
  \ }
```

Comment: Why don't you ask that on the plugin's issue tracker?

Comment: @romainl Because I have a feeling it has to do with string concatenation. When I do `"foo" . fugitive#statusline()`, then the result is `foo,GIT(master)`, but if I do `fugitive#statusline() . "foo"` then the result is `GIT(master)foo` with no comma. If I do `"foo" . fugitive#head()` then the result is `foomaster` with no comma! That led me to believe that maybe I don't know as much as I thought about string concatenation. It seems likely not to be related to the plugin.

Comment: As @romainl said this issue comes from `vim-fugitive`; See [these lines of source code](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/444ba9fda5d05aa14c7e8664fa4a66a59c62a550/plugin/fugitive.vim#L3033-L3037)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This code in the fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/444ba9fda5d05aa14c7e8664fa4a66a59c62a550/plugin/fugitive.vim#L3033-L3037) either prepends a comma, or encloses the element in square braces. These two styles are also offered by the built-in statusline elements.

You can remove the undesired comma by taking only a substring (`[1:]`) off the result of the fugitive invocation:

```
'fugitive': '%{exists("*fugitive#statusline") ? "⎇ " . fugitive#statusline()[1:] : ""}'
```